# How to use vertices transformed by vertex shader in pixel shader?

Tags: stream, load, output, shader, directx-11

I'm using DirectX 11. I wanna use all vertices transformed by vertex shader in pixel shader. I found out that there is Stream-Output Stage and that the Stream-output data from vertex shader can be read by programmable shaders using load functions(Load()). but I can't find how to use the load function in pixel shader.

I wanna know how to use the load function in pixel shader and get all the transformed vertices.
Or are there other ways to use transformed vertices in pixel shader?